# Find permanent deletion date for soft deleted blobs in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, soft-delete

I deleted a lot of blobs (50TB+) several weeks ago in my Azure Storage account that is protected with soft delete. The soft delete was configured with 14 days retention, which I later changed to 7 days.

However, 14 days have passed and the blobs are still not permanently deleted, as I can still see them when selecting 'Show deleted blobs' in the Azure Portal.
This also means I am still being charged for storage.

Is there a way to find out the actual deletion date of a blob? I also see under Insights that the used capacity is still unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using REST API, when you list the blobs with `deleted` as one of the values for `include` parameter (so that the listing results contain soft deleted blobs), you can find this information by inspecting two properties in the result:

- `Deleted-Time`: It will tell you the date/time when the blob was deleted.
- `RemainingRetentionDays`: It will tell you the number of days remaining after which the blob will be permanently deleted from storage.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#response-body):

> For version 2017-07-29 and above, Deleted, DeletedTime and
> RemainingRetentionDays appear when this operation includes the
> include={deleted} parameter. These elements do not appear if this blob
> was not deleted. These elements appear for blob or snapshot that are
> deleted with DELETE operation when soft delete feature was enabled.
> Deleted element is set to true for blobs and snapshots that are soft
> deleted. **Deleted-Time corresponds to time when the blob was deleted.
> RemainingRetentionDays indicates number of days after which soft
> deleted blob will be permanently deleted by blob service.**

If you're using [`Azure.Storage.Blobs (.Net SDK)`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs), you will find this information in the following properties: [`BlobItemProperties.DeletedOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobitemproperties.deletedon?view=azure-dotnet) and [`BlobItemProperties.RemainingRetentionDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobitemproperties.remainingretentiondays?view=azure-dotnet).

For other languages, you can search for similar properties in the respective SDKs.

**UPDATE**

Please try the following:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName account-name -StorageAccountKey account-key
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 001-000 -IncludeDeleted -Context $context
$blobs.ICloudBlob.Properties | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output will be something like the following. The first blob below is not deleted thus `DeletedTime` and `RemainingDaysBeforePermanentDelete` will be null. The second blob is soft-deleted and it will have these values populated.

```
{
    "CacheControl":  null,
    "ContentDisposition":  null,
    "ContentEncoding":  null,
    "ContentLanguage":  null,
    "Length":  89,
    "ContentMD5":  "nax+W2kkfQqP8+K6dj2uFw==",
    "ContentType":  "image/svg+xml",
    "ETag":  "\"0x8D951D0C90A29CA\"",
    "Created":  "\/Date(1627481141000)\/",
    "LastModified":  "\/Date(1627481141000)\/",
    "BlobType":  2,
    "LeaseStatus":  2,
    "LeaseState":  1,
    "LeaseDuration":  0,
    "PageBlobSequenceNumber":  null,
    "AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount":  null,
    "IsServerEncrypted":  true,
    "IsIncrementalCopy":  false,
    "StandardBlobTier":  null,
    "RehydrationStatus":  null,
    "PremiumPageBlobTier":  null,
    "BlobTierInferred":  null,
    "BlobTierLastModifiedTime":  null,
    "DeletedTime":  null,
    "RemainingDaysBeforePermanentDelete":  null
},
{
    "CacheControl":  null,
    "ContentDisposition":  null,
    "ContentEncoding":  null,
    "ContentLanguage":  null,
    "Length":  98024,
    "ContentMD5":  "/uZucSqKCO71gFpGiSkyrQ==",
    "ContentType":  "application/font-woff",
    "ETag":  "\"0x8D951D0C90AC631\"",
    "Created":  "\/Date(1627481141000)\/",
    "LastModified":  "\/Date(1627481141000)\/",
    "BlobType":  2,
    "LeaseStatus":  0,
    "LeaseState":  0,
    "LeaseDuration":  0,
    "PageBlobSequenceNumber":  null,
    "AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount":  null,
    "IsServerEncrypted":  true,
    "IsIncrementalCopy":  false,
    "StandardBlobTier":  null,
    "RehydrationStatus":  null,
    "PremiumPageBlobTier":  null,
    "BlobTierInferred":  null,
    "BlobTierLastModifiedTime":  null,
    "DeletedTime":  "\/Date(1627481162000)\/",
    "RemainingDaysBeforePermanentDelete":  9
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried listing the blobs to get the retentiondays, however, that seems to have exposed the actual issue. If I list the blobs (via powershell) they already seem deleted (using -IncludeDeleted) and I get no blob-results. However, the Portal still displays the blobs and its storage usage. Any ideas?

Comment: Try running your PowerShell cmdlet with `-debug` paremeter. That should give you more idea about why soft-deleted blobs are not returned. It may very well be an issue with Azure PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt show any obvious issues DEBUG: AzureQoSEvent: CommandName - Get-AzStorageBlob; IsSuccess - True; Duration - 00:00:05.7182680;
DEBUG: Finish sending metric.
DEBUG: 15:47:37 - GetAzureStorageBlobCommand end processing.

Comment: Thanks, however, that only works if I get any blobs as a result of the Get. It works if I run it on a container/folderprefix that has blobs dat are not deleted. But if I run it on a container/folder that only contains soft-deleted blobs I get nothing...

Comment: `But if I run it on a container/folder that only contains soft-deleted blobs I get nothing...` - I just tried it on one of my blob container. That had 13 blobs in soft-deleted state and I was able to get proper results. Please check if you're getting `ContinuationToken` back in response. See this [`example`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-AzStorageblob?view=azps-6.2.1#example-4--list-blobs-in-multiple-batches).

Comment: not getting that either...I'm afraid the storage account is somehow messed up. I'll wait a couple of more days to see what happens and I'm afraid I have to pay for azure technical support. thanks either way